# Logo's background red-color contrast (popcorn icon)

Tags: discussion, design

Maybe it is only me, but I think the popcorn icon in the logo of MOVIES&TV needs to be adjusted a little bit to make the two different shades of red more contrasting, or at least easier to spot.

Have a look at the image below. I noticed that the meta site already has a good contrasting shade of grey.

PS: I am not a designer, nor do I have any speciality in selecting colors that go together, but I've discovered that there is a darker red in the logo by coincidence and thought: maybe they should have selected another tone. I could be wrong.

[image: Logos contrast]

Comment: Contrast looks fine to me, but I'm color blind so what do I know? :P

Comment: LOL, I didn't even realize there was a circle around it until I read this question.  So, yeah.  Maybe an adjustment is in order.  :o)